# How to set the badge to SegmentedButton with Secha Touch UI?

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch

How to set the badge to SegmentedButton with Secha Touch 2.0.2

```js
var segmentedButton = new Ext.SegmentedButton({
    allowMultiple: true,
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Option 1',
        },
        {
            text   : 'Option 2',
            pressed: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Option 3'
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        toggle: function(container, button, pressed){
            console.log("User toggled the '" + button.text + "' button: " + (pressed ? 'on' : 'off'));
        }
    }
});
Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'container', padding: 10, items: [segmentedButton] });
```

[image]

like this:
[image]

Anyone know how to do that? it's better to do with SegmentedButton

Answer (score 0):

Use [`badgeText`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-badgeText):

> Optional badge text.

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f5m